# JavaFX Box of CheckBox Align Right

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, checkbox

I want to align the `.box` portion of a CheckBox to the right. It is graphic only, so there is no text. Here's a picture where I set the `.check-box` to have a light blue background, so I can see the entire width of the Control.

[image: CheckBoxScreenshot]

No matter what I try, including `-fx-alignment: center-right`, `-fx-text-align: right`, or even changing the alignment of the HBox it's contained in to right, will change it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `-fx-alignment:center-right;` works fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite mentioning that `-fx-alignment: center-right;` did not work, you can use that very CSS property to do what you want.

Example code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static String appCss() {
        // Uses text blocks; requires Java 15+
        // Uses data URL; requires JavaFX 17+
        return """
                data:text/css,
                .root {
                    -fx-padding: 10px;
                }

                .check-box {
                    -fx-max-width: Infinity;
                    -fx-background-color: #add8e6ff;
                    -fx-alignment: center-right;
                }

                .check-box .box {
                    -fx-background-color: #ff4c00ff;
                }

                .check-box:selected .mark {
                    -fx-background-color: white;
                }
                """;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        HBox root = new HBox(checkBox);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        HBox.setHgrow(checkBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 75);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(appCss());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Output (after selecting the check box):

[image: Snapshot of application from example code]

The above was tested on JavaFX 20.0.1. If you cannot get this to work in your own code, then I suggest editing your question to include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Funny enough, I was able to resolve my issue using something ELSE in your code example. I was binding the width of the checkbox to half the width of the HBox, and for some reason, this was preventing the alignment of the CheckBox to the right. I switched to using HBox.setHGrow and now it works! Thanks for indirectly solving my problem XD

Comment: Glad I could help, even if indirectly. Note you should never try to bind a child's dimensions to its parent's dimensions. That tends to mess up the layout system. Always try to use the mechanisms provided by the layout. You can always create your own layout, and override `layoutChildren()`, if no built-in nor third-party layout, or combination of such layouts, does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can achieve the alignment you want directly in Java code. Here's how you can do it:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckBoxAlignmentExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setStyle("-fx-alignment: center-right;");
        
        HBox hbox = new HBox(checkBox);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("CheckBox Alignment Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, I have tried both setting the checkbox alignment to center right, and the HBox alignment to center right, and neither work.